# prompt empty not showing up clistdata

Tags: yii

When the list is empty it's not showing up. It'll show up when I remove the array in 3rd parameter of dropdownlist, but my class won't work if that happens. What am I missing here?

```
array('name'=>'response',
    type'=>'raw',
    'header'=>'Send a Note',
    'value'=>function($data,$row){
    if ($data->response_id ===null ||$data->response_id ==11)
        return CHtml::dropDownList('Response','',
        CHtml::listData(table::model()->findAll(),
                'response_id','response','',array('prompt'=>'Select a message')),
        array('class'=>'changeStatus','id' => $data->response,'url'=>Yii::app()->createURL('url')));
        else return $data->response->response;
        }
),
```

Comment: what is not being showing up?dropDown list?

Comment: dropdownlist is showing,.. the empty prompt select message isn't